# Add a matching to a Hamiltonian path to reduce the max distance between given pairs of vertices

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, np-hardness, np-complete

What is the complexity of the following problem?

**Input**:

- $H$ a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in [$K_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)
- $R \subseteq [n]^2$ a subset of pairs of vertices
- a positive integer $k$

**Query**: is there a [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) $M$ such that 
for every $(v,u) \in R$, $d_G(v,u) \leq k$?
(where $G = ([n], M\cup H)$)

I have been having a discussion with a friend about this problem. 
My friend thinks the problem is in polynomial time. 
I think it is NP-complete.

Comment: You can simplify this further, at least in terms of presentation. You are given $k$, a path with $n$ vertices, and a collection $R$ of pairs of these vertices. You want to augment the path with a matching so that the distance between any pair in $R$ is at most $k$.

Comment: I think this formulation may be confusing after my latest edit to remove some ambiguity.

Comment: My interpretation is correct, isn't it?

Comment: I did an edit to make the problem statement more rigorous. I think this can be further simplified because as you can simply assume that H is the Hamiltonian path 1-2-3-4-5...-n without loss of generality. So you just need $n$.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is incorrect**.

Your friend is right. Your problem (as interpreted by Sasho) does not place any restriction on the cardinality of the matching $C$. Therefore, choose $C$ to be a matching between the pairs in $R$. Then for any positive integer $k$, the distance between every pair in $R$ is less than $k$.

Your problem becomes interesting if you force paths to contain edges from both the matching $C$ and the path $P$.

Comment: What do you mean by “matching between the pairs in $R$”?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It means connecting the nodes of every pair in $R$ by an edge. So $C$ is just $R$ with an edge connecting every pair. This is equivalent to augmenting the path $P$ with a perfect marching on the pairs of $R$.

Comment: That does not seem to make much sense to me. What if $R$ is not a matching? Say, if $R$ contains the pairs $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$, how do you choose $C$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes. Your point is valid. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @pfim Can the shortest path be formed using only edges from $C$?

Comment: I don't see how picking a perfect matching in $R$ enforces that the shortest paths between each pair of vertices in $R$ do not exceed $K$.

I think it is clear from my question that the shortest paths may use edges from $P$, and I don't see that a constraint forcing this is necessary. (EDIT: Just saw your comment. The answer is no, shortest paths can use edges from $P$.)

Comment: I've clarified this issue in my question. Thanks for finding this ambiguity!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** the answer below is not correct, because I wrongly assumed that the Hamiltonian path is in an arbitrary graph, not in $K_n$. I leave it undeleted, perhaps I'll be able to fix it or it will give some hints for another answer.

I think it's NP-complete. This is a very informal/quick reduction idea from 3SAT

For every variable $x_i$ add a "variable gadget" with:

- three nodes $X_i, +X_i, -X_i$
- two variable edges $(X_i,+X_i)$ and $(X_i,-X_i)$

Add a source node $S$ and connect it to all variables $X_i$.

For each clause $C_j$ add a node $C_j$ and connect it to the corresponding variables $+X_i$ or $-X_i$ that forms the clause.

The following picture represents: $(+x_1 \lor -x_2 \lor -x_3) \land (-x_2 \lor x_3 \lor x_4)$

[image]

The set $R$ (nodes that must be linked) contains  $(S, C_1), (S,C_2), ...$

The simple path $P$ should include all "BLUE" edges except the variable edges $(X_i, +X_i)$ and $(X_i, -X_i)$ (in the picture above the blue edges represent the edges that we include in $P$).

At this point, the initial formula is satisfiable if and only if the shortest path from $S$ to each clause node $C_j$ is not greater than three. Indeed to reach a clause from $S$ in three steps we must traverse at least one variable $X_i$: $S \to X_i \to \pm X_i \to C_j$. So we must traverse one of the two edges:  $X_i \to +X_i$ or $X_i \to -X_i)$ and include it into $C$ (because by construction it's not part of $P$). But both cannot be included, because they share a vertex.

**But** we're not sure that we can build a **simple** path $P$ that includes all the blue edges because some nodes have more than one incident blue edge.

To fix this we replace each node with multiple incident blue edges, with a  tree that contains only pairs of incident blue edges that will be included in $P$ and edges that separate them and that should be included in $C$ to reach the clause nodes:

[image]

The original graph becomes:

[image]

Each tree should have the same depth (we just can pick the max of the depth required for all the clauses/variables/S); and we must increase the value of $K$ accordingly (the number of steps to reach $C_j$ from $S$).

We can include in $C$ all the needed (not blue) edges required to reach the clause nodes because they share no vertex.

Furthermore with this construction we are able to build a simple path $P$ that traverse each vertex and each blue edge, just add extra nodes to avoid shortcuts between the clauses or variables:

[image]

Comment: Trying to build a path that contains all the blue edges worries me: some vertices have more than 2 blue edges incident on them, so there can't be any single simple path including all the blue edges.

Comment: Ok, thank you ... I completely forgot what is a simple path :-( ... now it should be fixed.

Comment: This post on math.SE  suggests that the problem may not be NP-complete. It could be intractable but solvable in quasipolynomial time http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218929/path-augmentation-to-minimize-the-diameter

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany: do you see a flaw in the current version of the answer?

Comment: No, I don't see any obvious flaw.

Comment: I see a pretty big issue: there's not actually anything causing the clauses to connect to the variables you want. When augmenting the path with a matching, the clauses can connect to literals that are not even in the clause just as much as it can connect to literals in the clause..

Comment: The node $S$ must be connected to all $C_j$ (because we include the pairs in $R$) with a path not longer than $K$ (that must be adjusted according to the sum of the depths of the trees used to split the blue edges, K=11 in the example). If for a variable there is no need to add the edge $(X_i,+X_i)$ or $(X_i,-X_i)$, then all clauses are satisfied whatever truth value we assign to it. What matters here is the existence of a short path from $S$ to all $C_j$s, and the $\leq K$ path condition doesn't allow to use a clause $C_j$ as a "bridge" to connect $S$ to another clause $C_j'$

Comment: I think Mikhail's objection is that in the penultimate figure, where $S$ connects directly to two nodes from its tree, nothing prevents the matching from linking each of those nodes directly to a $C_j$ for a path of length 2. In fact, in the original graph nothing stops the matching from connecting $S$ directly to a $C_j$ which can't be satisfied.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: perhaps I don't understand the objection; what do you mean with "... where S connects directly to two nodes from its tree..."? In the original question, the picked edges of the matching must belong to the original edge set E of the graph ("*... if there is some subset of edges C you can chose from E ...*"). I think that Kaveh reformulation is not correct: the Hamiltonian path is not from $K_n$ but from an arbitrary graph $G$.

Comment: The reformulation is correct: the original question said "*Suppose you have a complete graph $G=(V,E)$...*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor: :-( you're right! I leave the answer and see if it can be fixed, or give some hints for another answer.